# Does anyone know how to resolve this error -SerenityManagedException: 'java.util.Set io.restassured.config.LogConfig.blacklistedHeaders()'

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

My Serenity Cucumber Project is throwing this error on execution . Please help

```
public Response callRestHttpGet(String baseURL, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> headers) {
        log.info("Step.1 PREPARING REST REQUEST TO MAKE A GET CALL");
        RequestSpecification httpGetRequest = SerenityRest.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation(); 
        log.info("Step.2 SETTING UP THE BASE URL:" + baseURL);
        httpGetRequest.baseUri(baseURL);
        log.info("Step.3 ADDING REQUEST HEADERS FOR THE GET CALL:" + headers.toString());
        Map<String, String> requestHeadersMap = new HashMap<String, String>(headers);
        httpGetRequest.headers(requestHeadersMap);
        log.info("Step.4 PERFORMING GET CALL");
        Response httpGetResponse = httpGetRequest.get();
        return httpGetResponse;
    }
```

Error I'm getting :

```
StepDefinition.call_the_apigee_inquiry_endpoint(String)
      **net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: 'java.util.Set io.restassured.config.LogConfig.blacklistedHeaders()'**
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.utils.RestReportingHelper.registerCall(RestReportingHelper.java:69)
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.reportQuery(RequestSpecificationDecorated.java:292)
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.execute(RequestSpecificationDecorated.java:284)
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.get(RequestSpecificationDecorated.java:67)
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.get(RequestSpecificationDecorated.java:56)
    at net.serenitybdd.rest.decorators.request.RequestSpecificationDecorated.get(RequestSpecificationDecorated.java:38)
    at automation.eft.modernization.utils.RestUtility.callRestHttpGet(RestUtility.java:37)
```

Comment: Which serenity version are you using?

Comment: <serenity.version>2.1.7</serenity.version>

Comment: It's kind of old version Serenity with Rest-assured version 3.3.0 Try to upgrade and run test one more time. https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core#what-is-the-latest-stable-version-i-should-use